# Palindrome function has logic error

Tags: php

I have written a function in PHP to check if a word/phrase is a palindrome but its not working.

I think there are some errors in it.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["text_string"])){
        //print("GET is set.<br />");       //test whether  GET works
        $inputText = $_GET["text_string"];
        // print("inputText value is: ".$inputText."<br />"); //test value of $inputText
        $inputText = stripslashes(trim($inputText));

        if($inputText == "") {
            $forwardText = $inputText;
            $reverseText = strrev($inputText);

            if(strcmp($forwardText, $reverseText) == 0){
                echo "<p class='yes'>The text you entered: <strong>'",$inputText, "'</strong> is a perfect palindrome!</p>";
            }else{
                echo "<p class='no'>The text you entered: <strong>'", $inputText,   "'</strong> is NOT a perfect palindrome.</p>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<p class='wrong'>Enter a word or phrase and click the 'Check for Perfect Palindrome' button.</p>";
        }      
    } 
    print("GET did not work.<br />");
?>
```

Comment: What is your error and how should this script work?

Comment: There is no error on the screen but its not giving the output, but on the url get is working

Comment: if ($inputText == "") { mean your code works only if nothing present. that a mistake.

Comment: if your PHP runs inside Apache, look at the error_log for messages that appear each time you load your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if ($inputText == "") {
```

change to

```
if ($inputText != "") {
```

also put this error message in a else condition.

```
else {
    print("GET did not work.<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
function isPalindrome($s){
    // Strip punctuaion
    $str = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/', '', $s);
    
    // Strip white space
    $str = explode(' ', $str);
    $str = implode('', $str);
    
    // Force lowercase
    $str = strtolower($str);
    
    // Reverse
    $rts = strrev($str);
    
    // Compare and show message
    $result = $str == $rts ? "It's a palindrome" : ":(" ;
    echo $result . '<br>';
}
 
$phrase1 = 'Red rum, sir, is murder?';
isPalindrome($phrase1);
 
$phrase2 = 'Red rum, sir, it is murder.';
isPalindrome($phrase2);
```